# "lftp" on RHEL6 fails to connect to vsftpd on RHEL7

Tags: rhel, vsftpd, lftp, gnutls

I have configured `vsftpd` on RHEL7 and i am trying to transfer data to it using `lftp` from RHEL6.

`lftp` seems to fail after sending the `PASS` command for `anonymous` login.

```
---> USER anonymous
<--- 331 Please specify the password.
---> PASS xxxxxx
**** gnutls_record_recv: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
---- Closing control socket
cd: Fatal error: gnutls_record_recv: An unexpected TLS packet was received.
```

The corresponding `vsftpd` log message:

```
Wed Mar 18 08:20:41 2020 [pid 37007] FTP command: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "USER anonymous"
Wed Mar 18 08:20:41 2020 [pid 37007] [anonymous] FTP response: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "331 Please specify the password."
Wed Mar 18 08:20:41 2020 [pid 37007] [anonymous] FTP command: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "PASS <password>"
Wed Mar 18 08:20:41 2020 [pid 37006] [cfgdb] OK LOGIN: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", anon password "xxxxxx"
```

But the same `lftp` works when connecting to a `vsftpd` configured on RHEL6. `vsftpd` logs from RHEL6 on successful connection:

```
Wed Mar 18 06:16:26 2020 [pid 706] FTP command: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "USER anonymous"
Wed Mar 18 06:16:26 2020 [pid 706] [anonymous] FTP response: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "331 Please specify the password."
Wed Mar 18 06:16:26 2020 [pid 706] [anonymous] FTP command: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "PASS <password>"
Wed Mar 18 06:16:26 2020 [pid 703] [cfgdb] OK LOGIN: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", anon password "xxxxxx"
Wed Mar 18 06:16:26 2020 [pid 709] [cfgdb] FTP response: Client "XX.XXX.XX.XX", "230 Login successful."
```

`lftp` version on RHEL6:

```
# lftp -v
LFTP | Version 4.0.9 | Copyright (c) 1996-2010 Alexander V. Lukyanov
```

`vsftpd` on RHEL7:

```
# vsftpd -v
vsftpd: version 3.0.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Managed to find the issue using `strace`.

When i debugged the `vsftpd` using `strace`, there was an error message `Cannot change directory`.

`vsftpd` tries to switch to the home directory of the `ftp_username` and when the directory was missing,  the `vsftpd` failed (though there was no error logged anywhere).

Creating the home directory for `ftp_username` fixed the issue.

Comment: `sudo mkhomedir_helper ftp_username`